# Center toast with image inside only?

Tags: android, center, toast

Is there any exist library that can display the toast like this app:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnYfQ.jpg

Or any snippet that can does this in the most elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may check [this link](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Toast_Alert_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=87&aaid=110) and make [custom toast](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/theming-toast-messages-with-the-android-sdk/) it'll help you

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout that you want to be shown the custom toast that you want to show.Now create a new Toast object.
    `Toast t = new Toast(YourActivity.this);`
Now inflate that custom view and set that view to be shown in the toast as follows
   `View v;
    //Inflate your custom view into this view`

Now set the custom view as view for the toast using `t.setView(v)`
Now to set the location of the toast shown you can set its gravity by using `t.setGravity()`
`